# Moving textarea on button click in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

[I have provided the image link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMY5o.jpg)

I Have serveral textarea and all these area have two buttons 1.Up 2.Down.
I want to change the position of textarea on the click of these buttons,How Can I achieve it in Angular.

My Code

```
     <textarea [disabled]="text_area_1_disabled" pInputTextarea cols="115" rows="4" [value]="first_text_area_value" [(ngModel)]="first_text_area_value" #first_text_area name="first_text_area"></textarea>
           </div>
          <div>
       <a>
          <img src="./assets/up.png" #text_area_1 (click)="moveUp()" class="operationBtn operationUpButton">
      </a>
     </div>
   <div>
     <a>
        <img src="./assets/down.png" #text_area_1 (click)="moveDown()" class="operationBtn operationUpButton">
     </a>
   </div>
</div>`
```

What should be the implementation in moveUp() and moveDown() Button,
Like above example I have total 6 textareas to move them up and down

Comment: Hi, welcome in StackOverflow. You should provide an example how what you tried so far so other users can help you exactly in the point that you missed

Comment: I dont have any idea how to implement this funcitonality so far, Also I have searched the web but didnt get anything that could help me

Comment: You can use something like an `ngClass` in your html, paired with two css classes like this `[ngClass]="clicked ? 'offset-style' : 'normal-style'"`. But this is all I can give you without some minimal code of your text areas. Also, I'm not clicking on random picture links. either post code or insert a picture, don't send me somewhere else.